# Keep which(..., arr.ind = TRUE) results that connect

Tags: r, algorithm, graph-theory

I am trying to take the results of a `which(..., arr.ind = TRUE)` function and remove the rows that are not the first to "connect" with one another.

**Examples:**

```
#example 1      example 2      example 3
   row col        row col        row col
     1   4          2   3          1   3
     2   4          2   4          2   5
     4   5          3   5          3   5
     3   6          2   7          4   6
     4   6          3   7          5   6
     3   7          4   7          6   8
     4   7          5   7          9  10
# should become (trimmed.mtx)
   row col        row col        row col
     1   4          2   3          1   3
     4   5          3   5          3   5
                    5   7          5   6
                                   6   8
```

These examples can be read in using:

```
example1 <- structure(list(row = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L), col = c(4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L)), .Names = c("row", "col"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
example2 <- structure(list(row = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), col = c(3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L)), .Names = c("row", "col"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
example3 <- structure(list(row = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 9L), col = c(3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 10L)), .Names = c("row", "col"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

The purpose of this is to take a dist matrix of Euclidean distances and turn it into a sequence of point-to-point distances that skip distances below a certain threshold. While there may be other ways to solve this problem, I am very interested in figuring out the best way to do this by filtering out rows from the which-matrix.

**Reproducible example of my intended use:**

```
set.seed(81417) # Aug 14th, 2017
# Generate fake location data (temporally sequential)

x <- as.matrix(cbind(x = rnorm(10, 10, 3), y =  rnorm(10, 10, 3)))

# Find euclidean point-to-point distances and remove distances that are less than:
value = 5
# I attempted to do so by calculating an entire Euclidean distance matrix (dist())
# and then finding a path from point-to-nearest-point 
# using distances that are greater than the value 
d <- as.matrix(dist(x[,c("x","y")]))
d[lower.tri(d)] <- 0
mtx <- which(d > value, arr.ind = T)
mtx

# Change from EVERY point-to-point distance (mtx) > value
# to only the "connecting" points that exceed the skipping value
trimmed.mtx <- {?}

# final result
cbind(x[unique(c(trimmed.mtx)),],d[trimmed.mtx])
```

Comment: Could you add seed so that the output for `mtx` is consistent? Nice question.

Comment: Also, will the object you are trying to trim always be ordered by the second column first, then the first?

Comment: No, the raw output of the which function is not ordered. I did `mtx[order(mtx[,"row"],)` to make it clearer for the reader. One could also do that ordering though if they want to order the object first.

Comment: This causes problems then.  Check this out: `set.seed(4)`. If you run `foo(data.frame(mtx, row.names = NULL))` you obtain a 4x2 object whereas `foo(data.frame(mtx[order(mtx[,1]), ], row.names = NULL))` returns a 3x2 object. There has to be some sort of general rule governing your "connections" as there could be more than one trimmed output given a certain ordering of the original.

Comment: @JosephWood it appears that the rule is that the connection in a lower row index would take precedence.  This would rule out matrix-based approaches that don't maintain some sort of precedence indicator.

Comment: I don't understand example 3 above.  Why is the expected output `[1,3][3,5]...` instead of `[1,3][2,5]...`

Comment: There is no [1,2] so there is no column 2 to connect to a row 2. There is only [1,3] where column 3 can connect row 3. ( given that [row,column] )

Comment: @JosephWood This is a very interesting aspect of the foo function you have pointed out. It seems to skip the first row because there is no immediate match for 9... It seems under my methodology, [1,9] (the first row) should be the final answer... hmm

Comment: @d.b have you seen the above mentioned result? `mtx <- structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 
8L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L
), .Dim = c(14L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "5", "1", "2", "7", "8", "1", "2", "7", "8"), c("row", "col"
)))`

Comment: @loki's function has the same issue. It appears a simple if statement may fix this.

Comment: @EvanFriedland, which issue?

Comment: If you run your function on the mtx in my comment - if row 1 does not connect with any other rows, it appears to move to another row?

Comment: @EvanFriedland, I checked it and the connecting rows resulting from mtx in your comment are `[2,5]->[5,7]->[7,9]`. If I change `mtx[1,2]` to 4 and `mtx[3,1]` to 5 (i.e. no connection between the first line and another), only the first row is returned. Isn't this the intention?

Comment: Originally I was thinking that the resulting connection chain would always stem from the first row in the mtx but now I see that has zero impact on my methodology. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a perfect problem for `Rcpp`. Observe:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerMatrix findConnections(IntegerMatrix m) {
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 1, n = m.nrow();

    // initialize matrix with same dimensions as m
    IntegerMatrix myConnections(n, 2);

    while (i < n) {
        // Populate with "connected" row
        myConnections(j,_) = m(i,_);

        // Search for next connection
        while (k < n && m(i, 1) != m(k, 0)) {k++;}
        i = k;
        j++;
    }

    // Subset matrix and output result
    IntegerMatrix subMatrix(j, 2);
    for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {subMatrix(i,_) = myConnections(i,_);}

    return subMatrix;
}


findConnections(as.matrix(example3))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    3    5
[3,]    5    6
[4,]    6    8
```

Here are the benchmarks on `example3` provided by the OP:

```
microbenchmark(get_path(example3),
               foo(example3),
               f(example3),
               findConnections(as.matrix(example3)))
Unit: microseconds
                                expr      min        lq       mean   median        uq        max neval cld
                  get_path(example3) 3345.999 3519.0255 6361.76978 3714.014 3892.9930 202511.942   100   b
                       foo(example3)  215.514  239.3230  360.81086  257.180  278.3200  10256.384   100  a 
                         f(example3)  936.355 1034.4645 1175.60323 1073.668 1142.4270   9676.755   100  a 
findConnections(as.matrix(example3))   52.135   60.3445   71.62075   67.528   80.4585    103.858   100  a
```

Here are some benchmarks on a larger example (didn't include `get_graph` as it was taking a very long time):

```
set.seed(6221)
x <- as.matrix(cbind(x = rnorm(1000, 10, 3), y =  rnorm(1000, 10, 3)))
value = 5
d <- as.matrix(dist(x[,c("x","y")]))
d[lower.tri(d)] <- 0
mtxLarge <- which(d > value, arr.ind = T)
mtxLargeFoo <- data.frame(mtxLarge, row.names = NULL) ## this is for the function foo
                                            ## as we don't want to include
                                            ## the time it takes to create
                                            ## a data.frame every time.

microbenchmark(foo(mtxLargeFoo),
               f(mtxLarge),
               findConnections(as.matrix(mtxLarge)), times = 10, unit = "relative")
Unit: relative
                                expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
                    foo(mtxLargeFoo) 3168.479 3376.909 2660.377 3424.276 2319.434 1960.161    10  b 
                         f(mtxLarge) 8307.009 8436.569 6420.919 8319.151 5184.557 4610.922    10   c
findConnections(as.matrix(mtxLarge))    1.000    1.000    1.000    1.000    1.000    1.000    10 a
```

Test for equality:

```
a <- findConnections(as.matrix(mtxLarge))
b <- foo(mtxLargeFoo)
c <- f(mtxLarge)
sapply(1:2, function(x) identical(a[,x], b[,x], c[, x]))
[1] TRUE TRUE
```

**UPDATE**
If `Rcpp` isn't your flavor, here is a Base R translation of the above code that is still faster than the other solutions:

```
findConnectionsBase <- function(m) {
    n <- nrow(m)
    myConnections <- matrix(integer(0), nrow = n, ncol = 2)
    i <- j <- 1L
    k <- 2L
    while (i <= n) {
        myConnections[j, ] <- m[i, ]
        while (k <= n && m[i, 2] != m[k, 1]) {k <- k + 1L}
        i <- k
        j <- j + 1L
    }
    myConnections[!is.na(myConnections[,1]), ]
}

microbenchmark(get_path(example3),
           foo(example3),
           f(example3),
           BaseR = findConnectionsBase(as.matrix(example3)),
           Rcpp = findConnections(as.matrix(example3)))
Unit: microseconds
              expr      min        lq       mean   median       uq        max neval cld
get_path(example3) 3128.844 3204.3765 6057.18995 3406.137 3849.274 188685.016   100   b
     foo(example3)  239.734  251.4325  399.71418  267.648  301.309  12455.441   100  a 
       f(example3)  899.409  961.3950 1145.72695 1014.555 1127.237   9583.982   100  a 
             BaseR   79.638   89.2850  103.63571   97.905  111.657    212.230   100  a 
              Rcpp   48.850   55.8290   64.24807   61.781   69.170    123.151   100  a
```

And for the larger example:

```
microbenchmark(foo(mtxLargeFoo),
               f(mtxLarge),
               BaseR = findConnectionsBase(as.matrix(mtxLarge)),
               Rcpp = findConnections(as.matrix(mtxLarge)), times = 10, unit = "relative")
               Unit: relative
            expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval  cld
foo(mtxLargeFoo) 2651.9626 2555.0515 1606.2785 1703.0256 1711.4850  671.9115    10   c 
     f(mtxLarge) 6812.7195 6433.2009 3976.6135 4218.1703 4105.1138 1642.2768    10    d
           BaseR  787.9947  733.4528  440.2043  478.9412  435.4744  167.7491    10  b  
            Rcpp    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    10 a
```

Comment: This is incredible. If I used Rccp or knew the language better I would give this as the correct answer. The speed is no joke. I will give you a +1 with the hopes someone else with a similar problem takes advantage of this.

Comment: I have given you the bounty for the above reason and because you went back to give a baseR answer that is very 3 times as fast as other options.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an idea using `igraph` package along with `zoo`,

```
get_path <- function(df){
  g1 <- graph_from_data_frame(df)
  l1 <- all_simple_paths(g1, 1)
  ind1 <- as.numeric(names(l1[[which.max(lengths(l1))]]))
  final_df <- setNames(as.data.frame(rollapply(ind1, 2, c)), 
                       c('row', 'col'))
  return(final_df)
}
```

which gives the following,

```
library(igraph)
library(zoo)
```

> ```
>  get_path(example1)
>  row col
> 1   1   4
> 2   4   5
>
> get_path(example2)
>   row col
> 1   2   3
> 2   3   5
> 3   5   7
>
> get_path(example3)
>   row col
> 1   1   3
> 2   3   5
> 3   5   6
> 4   6   8
> ```

Answer (score 3):

**FUNCTION**

```
foo = function(df){
    #Initiate with a value of 1 (first row)
    inds = 1
    while(TRUE){
        # Look for the first index where the 'row' is equal to the value
        # in 'col' at the index specified by the last value of 'inds'
        temp = tail(inds, 1)
        ind = temp + which(df[["row"]][(temp+1):NROW(df)] == df[["col"]][temp])[1]

        #Append 'ind' to 'inds'
        inds = c(inds, ind)

        #Iterate until the end of the rows or when NA is encountered
        if (ind == NROW(df) | is.na(ind)){
            #Return the subset of the df with appropirate rows
            return(df[inds[!is.na(inds)],])
        }
    }
}
```

**USAGE**

```
foo(example1)
#  row col
#1   1   4
#3   4   5

foo(example2)
#  row col
#1   2   3
#3   3   5
#7   5   7

foo(example3)
#  row col
#1   1   3
#3   3   5
#5   5   6
#6   6   8

foo(data.frame(mtx, row.names = NULL))
#   row col
#1    1   3
#5    3   4
#11   4   7
```

Comment: This works very well - I'm hoping you can flush out the answer by adding some code comments of how it explicitly works/what each line does? Then I would be happy to accept :)

Comment: Quick question, in your view, why did you choose to make this function work on data.frames as opposed to change the subsetting format from `[["row"]]` to `[,"row"]` - since `which()` results are always matrices?

Comment: Gah I see - dput of my examples ended up being data.frames - not matrices. This works for me either which way. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This function is applicable for matrices and data.frames with two columns.

```
f <- function(x){
  res <- x[1, ]          # first row as defined 
  tmpCol <- x[1,2]       # the target column for the "connection"
  while (TRUE){          # loop until breaked
    connectingRow <- x[which(x[, 1] == tmpCol)[1], ]  # get first matching row
    if (any(is.na(connectingRow))) return(res) 
    # if this row is not NA (which it would be if no connecting line is found) continue, 
    # else return the results

    # append connecting matches and set new tmpCol for reiteration. 
    res <- rbind(res, connectingRow)
    tmpCol <- res[nrow(res), 2]
  }
}

f(example1)
#   row col
# 1   1   4
# 3   4   5
f(example2)
#   row col
# 1   2   3
# 3   3   5
# 7   5   7
```

### Benchmarking

Benchmark comparison between @d.b's `foo()` and the above proposed `f()`

```
microbenchmark(f(mtx), foo(mtx))
# Unit: microseconds
#      expr    min     lq     mean median      uq      max neval cld
#    f(mtx) 18.204 19.058 22.61003 20.053 20.7640   64.851   100   a
#  foo(mtx) 14.506 15.075 73.97871 15.360 15.9285 5740.151   100   a
```

Answer (score 2):

For all you fans of functional programming, here's a recursive solution.  R is not optimized for this, but it most closely represents the abstract process that the OP is describing.

```
connected_rows <- function(df, next.row.val = NULL){
  if(is.null(next.row.val)){
    return( 
      rbind( 
        head(df,1), 
        Recall( 
          df = tail(df,-1), 
          next.row.val = head(df$col,1)
        )
      )
    )
  } else {
    next.row <- match(next.row.val,df$row)
    if(is.na(next.row)){
      return(NULL)
    } else {
      return(
        rbind(
          df[next.row,],
          Recall(
            df = tail(df,-next.row), 
            next.row.val = df$col[next.row]
          )
        )
      )
    }
  }
}

connected_rows(example1)
#   row col
# 1   1   4
# 3   4   5
connected_rows(example2)
#   row col
# 1   2   3
# 3   3   5
# 7   5   7
connected_rows(example3)
#   row col
# 1   1   3
# 3   3   5
# 5   5   6
# 6   6   8
```

Comment: I wrote this for fun.  It will probably break on large data.frames with an `evaluation nested too deeply` error.